# How to install specific version of bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, client

How do I install a specific version of `bitcoind`?

I want to install `bitcoind` version `0.12.1` in my system.

How can I do that?

I am trying to use bitcore's Insight Explorer in my project.  It uses version bitcoind v0.12 to query all those things that are shown in the UI... I have tried to run this with v0.14 but Insight UI crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code for Bitcoin Core, v0.12.1 can be downloaded directly from GitHub, via https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases/tag/v0.12.1

Binaries are available at:  https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.12.1/

Be aware, v0.12 has known vulnerabilities, and should not be used in new work.  https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0 shows some of the vulnerabilities that were fixed in v0.13.